# Printed items from LISt do not match what was inserted

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Sorry guys, a bit new to Python so please bear with me.

I am attempting, just for S and G's to create a small python program that will take X number of digits of Pi, and play them as winsound.beeps (don't ask).

I got the beeps to beep, and I got Pi inserted into a list. When i print the list, it's not correct. Can anyone point to what I may have done wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from mpmath import *

import winsound

mp.dps = 10

floatPi = mp.pi
print(floatPi)

conPi = str(floatPi)
print(conPi)

strPi = conPi.replace(".", "")
print(strPi)

listPi = []

for digit in strPi:
    listPi.append(int(digit))

print listPi
#winsound.Beep(floatPi*100, 300)

for number in listPi:
    print(listPi[number])
    #winsound.Beep(listPi[number]*100, 300)
```

Results are as follows

```
3.141592654
3.141592654
3141592654
[3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 4]
1
1
5
1
9
4
4
2
9
5
```

Why is the printed list from the for loop not Pi?

Comment: `for number in listPi:` what do you think that does?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following as your last for loop:

```
for number in listPi:
    print(number)
```

the for loop gives you the contents in the list one by one. You don't need to look up in the list again.

Comment: Happy to help. You could accept the answer if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be ,

```
for number in listPi:
    print(number)
```

Cause here you are iterating through the contents of the list not the keys associated with them , for example take the first case where it is `print(listPi[number])` it essentially prints `lisPi[3]` which is `1`.

And if you are from c/c++/java ,

```
for i in range(0,len(listPi),1):
    print(listPi[i])
```

This will be more familliar.